# SSL Certificate Error : ssl.ca.location failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making kafka consumer using SSL Certificate in asp.net c#. Below is my config

```
            var configSSL = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = groupID,
                BootstrapServers = serverUrl,
               SslCaLocation = "testcert.p12",            
                SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,              
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,                
                Debug = "all",
            };
```

I am getting error:
Error occurred: ssl.ca.location failed: No error

Answer (score 0):

From the error, can not read the `testcert.p12` file that you have define here

```
SslCaLocation = "testcert.p12",
```

Can not find the file to read it, or not have permissions to read it, or is not the correct file

Comment: Even i used full path , i am getting same error: var config = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "bootstrap.servers", "{server_hostname}:9093" }, { "security.protocol", "SSL" }, { "ssl.ca.location", @"C:\path\to\caroot\file\ca-root.crt" } } Error: Error occurred: ssl.ca.location failed: No error –

Comment: @kaushalrmgruv.hhprasadcdr this path `C:\path\to\caroot\file\` for sure have no permissions to read from asp.net